# Get Json from $http request

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Need help to make changes in Angular Factory. Have example working with array JSON data, but need this code work with JSON data from $http request, how do that?

This is example Factory:

```
    angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('catgs', function() {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var catgs = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'CATG1',
    items: [{
      img:'img/G1I1.png',
      name:'category1Item1',
      status:'OPEN'

       }]
  },{
    id: 1,
    name: 'CATG2',
    items: [{
      img:'img/G2I1.png',
      name:'category2Item1',
      status:'OPEN'

       },{
      img:'img/G2I2.png',
      name:'category2Item2',
      status:'CLOSED'

       }]
  }];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return catgs;
    },
    remove: function(catg) {
      catgs.splice(catgs.indexOf(catg), 1);
    },
    get: function(catgId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < catgs.length; i++) {
        if (catgs[i].id === parseInt(catgId)) {
          return catgs[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
});
```

Need help to replace catgs JSON data to $http request, for example musite.com/jsondata.json

Answer (score 1):

```
//try this
$http.get('your api url or .json').then(function(result){
   $scope.jsonData = result.data;
}, function(err) {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but you can show full Factory example?

Comment: yes i can show..so here what you can do fetch json via above code and you can return that obj so you can retrieve your json data in anywhere wherever your factory is being injected